# How to configure an exposed filter in a view using a date picker?

Tags: 8, views, datetime

How can I configure an exposed filter so that users can filter my site content by creation date, preferably using a date picker?

I tried using *Content: Authored on* as filter, but it gets me a text field to enter the date to enter a date/time in the *yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss* format, which makes entering the date more difficult for users and more error prone.

What is the difference between Drupal 8 and Drupal 7 with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 7.x-3?

Comment: Have you just tried adding one of the "Content: Created" filters (there are different flavors) and exposing it?

Comment: Not able to find "Content: Created" filter. Have "Content: Authored on", "content revision: Authored on" and "Taxonomy term: Post date" only.

Comment: Went by memory.  Does "Content: Authored on" work?

Comment: "Content: Authored on" gives a input box for users to enter date in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format, which is too complicated. How to show a date, month and year dropdown or date picker?

Comment: That isn't supported yet, https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950  I'm hoping that gets wrapped up this week and into 8.2.x.

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Answer (score 12):

You can use the [Date Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup) module.

> Adds the native HTML 5 date popup widget to all date fields in views
>   filters.

As the [Use form element of type date instead textfield when selecting a date in an exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950) is still in progress.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new patch released a few days ago, I test it in a project and it works fine. Here is the issue:

[Use form element of type date instead textfield when selecting a date in an exposed filter](https://www.drupal.org/node/2648950)

> Problem/Motivation
>
> When adding a datetime exposed filter I cannot simply select a date -
>   I have to manually enter a date which is very bad UX.

And the [patch is the number 65](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2648950-65.patch)

Answer (score 3):

The [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module integrates with the date type fields, including the date popup. You can use this module to easily add an exposed filter with the date popup.

Its in Beta for now but you can use it.

Comment: In case you're using entity api to add fields (via BaseFieldDefinitions), instead of field api: BEF does not work for datetime fields, only works for timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

Add the jquery date picker in for that page as dependency. `your_theme.libraries.yml`

```
date-picker:
  js:
    script/site-datepicker.js : {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.ui.datepicker
```

**site-datepicker.js**

```
Drupal.behaviors.customDatepicker = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    jQuery(function () {
      jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        altField: "input[data-drupal-selector=edit-created]",
        altFormat: "yy/mm/dd 23:59:59"
      });
    });
  }
};
```

**views-exposed-form--*views-block-name*.html.twig**

```
{% if q is not empty %}
  {#
    This ensures that, if clean URLs are off, the 'q' is added first,
    as a hidden form element, so that it shows up first in the POST URL.
  #}
  {{ q }}
{% endif %}

<input id="datepicker" type="text">
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-created" data-msg-maxlength="This field field has a maximum length of 128." name="created" size="30" maxlength="128" aria-invalid="false" type="hidden">
{{ form|without('created') }}
```