# How to use views exposed filters in d8?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view like as follows using exposed fliter fields in d6 , how can i recreate like that in d8 ?

Here the `from date` and `to date` is to be selected and result will come accordingly

for the date . Here the date field is exposed filter .

view page : [image]

and in view [image]

**How can i recreate a form like this using view in D8 ?**

For the same purpose in d8 i have only this option : Any help is appreciated .

[image]

Comment: Try 2 filters - one 'More than' and the other 'less then'.

Comment: I guess this is a similar question. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200787/expose-date-filter-in-view

Answer (score 3):

1) Checkmark ☑ expose filters

2) Select Single Filter

3) Select is between

[image]

which will result in

[image]

Unfortunately there is no way to do it in drop downs like you have it until the better exposed filters module gets ported.

Well you could do it in Drop downs using Group Filter with is between, but you would only be able to do it by year only though.

Comment: I am getting the error after saving the grouped field **InvalidArgumentException: The configuration property display.page_1.display_options.filters.field_deployment_date_value.group_info.group_items.1.value.type doesn't exist. in Drupal\Core\Config\Schema\ArrayElement->get() (line 79 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Schema/ArrayElement.php)**

Comment: I am getting error again while saving the grouped filters. **display.page_1.display_options.filters.field_deployment_date_value.group_info.group_items.1.value.type**

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich eeerrr, looks like we ran into a Drupal 8 bug **:(**

Comment: Yes , that field (field_deployment_date_value) already exists there .

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich I have reported the bug [Date Filter is broken](https://www.drupal.org/node/2738539)

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich As per [Lendude's comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/2738539#comment-11252389) turns out you cannot just type the year. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40643/discussion-between-icecreamsandwich-and-no-sssweat).