# Change exposed filter date format with Search API

Tags: views, 8, search, datetime

We are using **Search API** for a customer website and we have a **View** with a start and end date exposed filter.

The view only filters correctly if we use the **m/d/Y** format, which is not valid in Brazil, as we use the **d/m/Y** format (with the day first).

I tried to search for solutions, but mostly use **custom code** or use **Better Exposed Filters**, which is not stable in **Drupal 8**. **Date Popup** also doesn't work with Search API fields. Although they fixed it, they didn't release a new version since 2017 (the fix is only available in the dev branch I guess).

I tried to create a new **Date Format** in "Date and Time Formats" and set the date field to this format, but that doesn't work too.

Using non-stable modules is **not** a choice and I would prefer to solve this using only **Drupal UI** (not any custom code)

**View Settings**
[image: View Settings]

**Tried to filter from 18/04/2020 to 22/04/2020, there's a content written in 20/04/2020, but nothing is returned**
[image: Tried to filter from 18/04/2020 to 22/04/2020, there's a content written in 20/04/2020, but nothing is returned]

PS: The screenshots are in Portuguese (Brazil), sorry for that.

**Here's an export of the view, if that helps:**

```yaml
    uuid: e60ffc0d-fa69-4581-8ee5-585f128ffcec
    langcode: pt-br
    status: true
    dependencies:
      config:
        - field.storage.node.body
        - field.storage.node.field_tags
        - search_api.index.conteudo
        - taxonomy.vocabulary.tags
      module:
        - search_api
        - text
        - views_infinite_scroll
    id: busca
    label: Busca
    module: views
    description: ''
    tag: ''
    base_table: search_api_index_conteudo
    base_field: search_api_id
    display:
      default:
        display_plugin: default
        id: default
        display_title: Master
        position: 0
        display_options:
          access:
            type: none
            options: {  }
          cache:
            type: tag
            options: {  }
          query:
            type: views_query
            options:
              bypass_access: false
              skip_access: false
              preserve_facet_query_args: false
          exposed_form:
            type: input_required
            options:
              submit_button: Buscar
              reset_button: true
              reset_button_label: Limpar
              exposed_sorts_label: 'Ordenar por'
              expose_sort_order: true
              sort_asc_label: 'Ordem crescente'
              sort_desc_label: 'Ordem decrescente'
              text_input_required: 'Aplique um filtro para ver os resultados'
              text_input_required_format: raw_html
          pager:
            type: infinite_scroll
            options:
              items_per_page: 15
              offset: 0
              id: 0
              total_pages: null
              tags:
                previous: Anterior
                next: Próximo
              expose:
                items_per_page: false
                items_per_page_label: 'Items per page'
                items_per_page_options: '5, 10, 25, 50'
                items_per_page_options_all: false
                items_per_page_options_all_label: '- All -'
                offset: false
                offset_label: Offset
              views_infinite_scroll:
                button_text: 'Total de Resultados: @total | Carregar mais @next_page_count'
                automatically_load_content: false
          style:
            type: default
          row:
            type: fields
          fields:
            created:
              id: created
              table: search_api_datasource_conteudo_entity_node
              field: created
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              label: ''
              exclude: false
              alter:
                alter_text: false
                text: ''
                make_link: false
                path: ''
                absolute: false
                external: false
                replace_spaces: false
                path_case: none
                trim_whitespace: false
                alt: ''
                rel: ''
                link_class: ''
                prefix: ''
                suffix: ''
                target: ''
                nl2br: false
                max_length: 0
                word_boundary: true
                ellipsis: true
                more_link: false
                more_link_text: ''
                more_link_path: ''
                strip_tags: false
                trim: false
                preserve_tags: ''
                html: false
              element_type: ''
              element_class: created
              element_label_type: ''
              element_label_class: ''
              element_label_colon: false
              element_wrapper_type: ''
              element_wrapper_class: ''
              element_default_classes: true
              empty: ''
              hide_empty: false
              empty_zero: false
              hide_alter_empty: true
              click_sort_column: value
              type: timestamp
              settings:
                date_format: custom
                custom_date_format: d/m/Y
                timezone: ''
              group_column: value
              group_columns: {  }
              group_rows: true
              delta_limit: 0
              delta_offset: 0
              delta_reversed: false
              delta_first_last: false
              multi_type: separator
              separator: ', '
              field_api_classes: false
              field_rendering: true
              fallback_handler: search_api_date
              fallback_options:
                date_format: fallback
                custom_date_format: ''
                timezone: ''
                link_to_item: false
                use_highlighting: false
                multi_type: separator
                multi_separator: ', '
              entity_type: node
              plugin_id: search_api_field
            title:
              id: title
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: title
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              label: ''
              exclude: false
              alter:
                alter_text: false
                text: ''
                make_link: false
                path: ''
                absolute: false
                external: false
                replace_spaces: false
                path_case: none
                trim_whitespace: false
                alt: ''
                rel: ''
                link_class: ''
                prefix: ''
                suffix: ''
                target: ''
                nl2br: false
                max_length: 0
                word_boundary: true
                ellipsis: true
                more_link: false
                more_link_text: ''
                more_link_path: ''
                strip_tags: false
                trim: false
                preserve_tags: ''
                html: false
              element_type: ''
              element_class: title
              element_label_type: ''
              element_label_class: ''
              element_label_colon: false
              element_wrapper_type: ''
              element_wrapper_class: ''
              element_default_classes: true
              empty: ''
              hide_empty: false
              empty_zero: false
              hide_alter_empty: true
              click_sort_column: value
              type: string
              settings:
                link_to_entity: true
              group_column: value
              group_columns: {  }
              group_rows: true
              delta_limit: 0
              delta_offset: 0
              delta_reversed: false
              delta_first_last: false
              multi_type: separator
              separator: ', '
              field_api_classes: false
              field_rendering: true
              fallback_handler: search_api
              fallback_options:
                link_to_item: false
                use_highlighting: false
                multi_type: separator
                multi_separator: ', '
              plugin_id: search_api_field
            body:
              id: body
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: body
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              label: ''
              exclude: false
              alter:
                alter_text: false
                text: ''
                make_link: false
                path: ''
                absolute: false
                external: false
                replace_spaces: false
                path_case: none
                trim_whitespace: false
                alt: ''
                rel: ''
                link_class: ''
                prefix: ''
                suffix: ''
                target: ''
                nl2br: false
                max_length: 250
                word_boundary: true
                ellipsis: true
                more_link: false
                more_link_text: ''
                more_link_path: ''
                strip_tags: true
                trim: true
                preserve_tags: ''
                html: false
              element_type: ''
              element_class: body
              element_label_type: ''
              element_label_class: ''
              element_label_colon: false
              element_wrapper_type: ''
              element_wrapper_class: ''
              element_default_classes: true
              empty: ''
              hide_empty: false
              empty_zero: false
              hide_alter_empty: true
              click_sort_column: value
              type: text_default
              settings: {  }
              group_column: value
              group_columns: {  }
              group_rows: true
              delta_limit: 0
              delta_offset: 0
              delta_reversed: false
              delta_first_last: false
              multi_type: separator
              separator: ', '
              field_api_classes: false
              field_rendering: true
              fallback_handler: search_api
              fallback_options:
                link_to_item: false
                use_highlighting: false
                multi_type: separator
                multi_separator: ', '
              plugin_id: search_api_field
            field_tags:
              id: field_tags
              table: search_api_datasource_conteudo_entity_node
              field: field_tags
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              label: ''
              exclude: true
              alter:
                alter_text: false
                text: ''
                make_link: false
                path: ''
                absolute: false
                external: false
                replace_spaces: false
                path_case: none
                trim_whitespace: false
                alt: ''
                rel: ''
                link_class: ''
                prefix: ''
                suffix: ''
                target: ''
                nl2br: false
                max_length: 0
                word_boundary: true
                ellipsis: true
                more_link: false
                more_link_text: ''
                more_link_path: ''
                strip_tags: false
                trim: false
                preserve_tags: ''
                html: false
              element_type: ''
              element_class: ''
              element_label_type: ''
              element_label_class: ''
              element_label_colon: false
              element_wrapper_type: ''
              element_wrapper_class: ''
              element_default_classes: false
              empty: ''
              hide_empty: false
              empty_zero: false
              hide_alter_empty: true
              click_sort_column: target_id
              type: entity_reference_label
              settings:
                link: true
              group_column: target_id
              group_columns: {  }
              group_rows: true
              delta_limit: 0
              delta_offset: 0
              delta_reversed: false
              delta_first_last: false
              multi_type: separator
              separator: ', '
              field_api_classes: false
              field_rendering: true
              fallback_handler: search_api_entity
              fallback_options:
                link_to_item: false
                use_highlighting: false
                multi_type: separator
                multi_separator: ', '
                display_methods:
                  abrangencia_do_evento:
                    display_method: label
                  agendas:
                    display_method: label
                  albuns:
                    display_method: label
                    view_mode: default
                  autoria:
                    display_method: label
                  categoria_do_evento:
                    display_method: label
                  categorias_de_noticias:
                    display_method: label
                  categorias_do_banco_de_imagens:
                    display_method: label
                    view_mode: default
                  categorias_do_banco_de_videos:
                    display_method: label
                  grupo:
                    display_method: label
                  grupos:
                    display_method: label
                  grupos_de_links:
                    display_method: label
                  local_de_publicacao_do_evento:
                    display_method: label
                  representante_do_evento:
                    display_method: label
                  subdivisao_de_grupos:
                    display_method: label
                  tags:
                    display_method: label
                  tipo_do_evento:
                    display_method: label
              entity_type: node
              plugin_id: search_api_field
            created_1:
              id: created_1
              table: search_api_datasource_conteudo_entity_node
              field: created
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              label: ''
              exclude: true
              alter:
                alter_text: false
                text: ''
                make_link: false
                path: ''
                absolute: false
                external: false
                replace_spaces: false
                path_case: none
                trim_whitespace: false
                alt: ''
                rel: ''
                link_class: ''
                prefix: ''
                suffix: ''
                target: ''
                nl2br: false
                max_length: 0
                word_boundary: true
                ellipsis: true
                more_link: false
                more_link_text: ''
                more_link_path: ''
                strip_tags: false
                trim: false
                preserve_tags: ''
                html: false
              element_type: ''
              element_class: ''
              element_label_type: ''
              element_label_class: ''
              element_label_colon: false
              element_wrapper_type: ''
              element_wrapper_class: ''
              element_default_classes: true
              empty: ''
              hide_empty: false
              empty_zero: false
              hide_alter_empty: true
              click_sort_column: value
              type: timestamp
              settings:
                date_format: d_m_y
                custom_date_format: d/m/Y
                timezone: America/Sao_Paulo
              group_column: value
              group_columns: {  }
              group_rows: true
              delta_limit: 0
              delta_offset: 0
              delta_reversed: false
              delta_first_last: false
              multi_type: separator
              separator: ', '
              field_api_classes: false
              field_rendering: true
              fallback_handler: search_api_date
              fallback_options:
                date_format: fallback
                custom_date_format: ''
                timezone: ''
                link_to_item: false
                use_highlighting: false
                multi_type: separator
                multi_separator: ', '
              entity_type: node
              plugin_id: search_api_field
          filters:
            search_api_fulltext:
              id: search_api_fulltext
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: search_api_fulltext
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              operator: and
              value: ''
              group: 1
              exposed: true
              expose:
                operator_id: search_api_fulltext_op
                label: 'Termo da Pesquisa'
                description: ''
                use_operator: false
                operator: search_api_fulltext_op
                identifier: search_api_fulltext
                required: true
                remember: false
                multiple: false
                remember_roles:
                  authenticated: authenticated
                  anonymous: '0'
                  administrator: '0'
                  publicador_basico: '0'
                  publicador_presi: '0'
                  jornalista: '0'
                  publicidade: '0'
                placeholder: 'Digite o termo da pesquisa'
                operator_limit_selection: false
                operator_list: {  }
              is_grouped: false
              group_info:
                label: ''
                description: ''
                identifier: ''
                optional: true
                widget: select
                multiple: false
                remember: false
                default_group: All
                default_group_multiple: {  }
                group_items: {  }
              parse_mode: terms
              min_length: null
              fields: {  }
              plugin_id: search_api_fulltext
            created:
              id: created
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: created
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              operator: '>='
              value:
                min: ''
                max: ''
                value: ''
                type: date
              group: 1
              exposed: true
              expose:
                operator_id: created_op
                label: 'Data inicial'
                description: ''
                use_operator: false
                operator: created_op
                identifier: initial_date
                required: false
                remember: false
                multiple: false
                remember_roles:
                  authenticated: authenticated
                  anonymous: '0'
                  administrator: '0'
                  publicador_basico: '0'
                  publicador_presi: '0'
                  jornalista: '0'
                  publicidade: '0'
                placeholder: 'Data inicial'
                min_placeholder: ''
                max_placeholder: ''
                operator_limit_selection: false
                operator_list: {  }
              is_grouped: false
              group_info:
                label: ''
                description: ''
                identifier: ''
                optional: true
                widget: select
                multiple: false
                remember: false
                default_group: All
                default_group_multiple: {  }
                group_items: {  }
              plugin_id: search_api_date
            created_1:
              id: created_1
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: created
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              operator: '<='
              value:
                min: ''
                max: ''
                value: ''
                type: date
              group: 1
              exposed: true
              expose:
                operator_id: created_1_op
                label: 'Data final'
                description: ''
                use_operator: false
                operator: created_1_op
                identifier: final_date
                required: false
                remember: false
                multiple: false
                remember_roles:
                  authenticated: authenticated
                  anonymous: '0'
                  administrator: '0'
                  publicador_basico: '0'
                  publicador_presi: '0'
                  jornalista: '0'
                  publicidade: '0'
                placeholder: 'Data final'
                min_placeholder: ''
                max_placeholder: ''
                operator_limit_selection: false
                operator_list: {  }
              is_grouped: false
              group_info:
                label: ''
                description: ''
                identifier: ''
                optional: true
                widget: select
                multiple: false
                remember: false
                default_group: All
                default_group_multiple: {  }
                group_items: {  }
              plugin_id: search_api_date
            status:
              id: status
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: status
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              operator: '='
              value: '1'
              group: 1
              exposed: false
              expose:
                operator_id: ''
                label: ''
                description: ''
                use_operator: false
                operator: ''
                identifier: ''
                required: false
                remember: false
                multiple: false
                remember_roles:
                  authenticated: authenticated
                operator_limit_selection: false
                operator_list: {  }
              is_grouped: false
              group_info:
                label: ''
                description: ''
                identifier: ''
                optional: true
                widget: select
                multiple: false
                remember: false
                default_group: All
                default_group_multiple: {  }
                group_items: {  }
              plugin_id: search_api_boolean
            field_tags:
              id: field_tags
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: field_tags
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              operator: or
              value: {  }
              group: 1
              exposed: true
              expose:
                operator_id: field_tags_op
                label: 'Tags de notícias'
                description: ''
                use_operator: false
                operator: field_tags_op
                identifier: field_tags
                required: false
                remember: false
                multiple: false
                remember_roles:
                  authenticated: authenticated
                  anonymous: '0'
                  administrator: '0'
                  publicador_basico: '0'
                  publicador_presi: '0'
                  jornalista: '0'
                  publicidade: '0'
                reduce: false
                operator_limit_selection: false
                operator_list: {  }
              is_grouped: false
              group_info:
                label: ''
                description: ''
                identifier: ''
                optional: true
                widget: select
                multiple: false
                remember: false
                default_group: All
                default_group_multiple: {  }
                group_items: {  }
              reduce_duplicates: false
              type: select
              limit: true
              vid: tags
              hierarchy: false
              error_message: true
              plugin_id: search_api_term
          sorts:
            created:
              id: created
              table: search_api_index_conteudo
              field: created
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              order: DESC
              exposed: false
              expose:
                label: 'Ordenar por data'
              plugin_id: search_api
          title: Busca
          header: {  }
          footer: {  }
          empty:
            area_text_custom:
              id: area_text_custom
              table: views
              field: area_text_custom
              relationship: none
              group_type: group
              admin_label: ''
              empty: true
              tokenize: false
              content: 'Sua busca não retornou nenhum resultado.'
              plugin_id: text_custom
          relationships: {  }
          arguments: {  }
          display_extenders: {  }
          css_class: search-result
          use_ajax: true
          filter_groups:
            operator: AND
            groups:
              1: AND
        cache_metadata:
          max-age: -1
          contexts:
            - 'languages:language_content'
            - 'languages:language_interface'
            - url
            - url.query_args
            - user
          tags:
            - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
            - 'config:field.storage.node.field_tags'
      page_1:
        display_plugin: page
        id: page_1
        display_title: Page
        position: 1
        display_options:
          display_extenders: {  }
          path: busca
          exposed_block: false
        cache_metadata:
          max-age: -1
          contexts:
            - 'languages:language_content'
            - 'languages:language_interface'
            - url
            - url.query_args
            - user
          tags:
            - 'config:field.storage.node.body'
            - 'config:field.storage.node.field_tags'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to this problem would be a date picker widget. This removes the need for the user to type dates in a specific format.

You should check out the [Date Popup](https://www.drupal.org/project/date_popup) module.

Reference: [milkovsky's answer to #200787](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246184/82623)

Comment: As I mentioned, Date Popup works with Search API only in the development version. In any case, I convinced the customer to use the development version, so, problem solved.

Comment: Nice! Sorry I must have missed that when I read the question.